# How to semantically have two lines (span two rows) in one <tr>?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about having two lines (visually two rows) but in one  element so the two lines are semantically linked and not treated as two separate items.

What I am trying to achieve is a table like this, ideally without using grid etc but if you think it would be necessary to use grid if it definitely won't work with  on its own, please let me know:

```
----------------------------
| id   | col 1   | col 3   |
----------------------------
| 1    | text    | text    |
| row that relates to id 1 |
----------------------------
| 2    | text    | text    |
| row that relates to id 2 |
----------------------------
```

This is the html I have at the moment:

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td colspan=3 style="display: block;">helloooooooooooo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to set that extra cell inside a new tr , so semanticaly it is correct and will be showing as expected. If you want to use a grid-layout instead a table-layout, the table tags will require also that extra tr for that spanning cell, to keep the code semanticaly correct :( . td displayed as table-cell among a td displayed as a block will do a single line

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it would, if he removed the `display: block;` inline style, that is applying the `colspan=3` to take up 3 times the width of the first column, not covering all three columns

Comment: display:block removed will set back the td to display:table-cell , it won't wrap. tr display is to be reset and that kills the all table-layout . What he wants is of course possible ... display reset here and there will do, but the structure won't be semanticaly correct as he is asking too ;) @BeerusDev

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Ahhh

Comment: here is a grid possibility with your html structure https://jsfiddle.net/f8aw5gub/ that extra td makes the table structure not correct, because of columns missing cells on some rows ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thank you for the jsfiddle, I thought I would probably need to use a different display type for the table. If you'd like to post it as an answer, I'd happily accept it as best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from comments:

> here is a `grid` possibility with your html structure https://jsfiddle.net/f8aw5gub/ that extra `td` makes the table structure not correct, because of columns missing cells on some rows ;)

The idea is to set the table to `display:grid;` and virtually remove all the tags in between the table and the cells via `display:contents;`, so the cells(`th`/`td`) can be direct children to fill the grid.

here is the code from the jsfiddle I linked earlier, that works if `display:contents` is supported, *but if you can, reconsider the HTML structure.*

```css
table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px;
  gap: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

th,
td {
  border: solid 1px;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr {
  display: contents;
}

[colspan="3"] {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

tr:nth-child(even) > * {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>col 1</th>
          <th>col 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td colspan="3">helloooooooooooo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td colspan="3">helloooooooooooo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td colspan="3">helloooooooooooo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td>text</td>
          <td colspan="3">helloooooooooooo</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close with your attempt.

First things first, you shouldn't use inline styling in HTML it is bad practice.

Secondly, you are using `display: block;` on a `<td>` element which isn't going to work. This behavior has to do with how are tables treated on browsers.

The table element is set as `display:table`. The tr is a `display:table-row`, and the td is `display:table-cell`.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>col 1</th>
    <th>col 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan=3>ID 1 Information</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan=3>ID 2 Information</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this separates ID 1 information into its own row rather than being included in the same one (so they're semantically linked). Also, thanks for the tip about inline styling - I usually just use it to test things but put it in its own css class once I am happy with it.